# HTML Link Helper full_calendar plugin breaks links

Tags: cakephp, fullcalendar, cakephp-2.0

I'm using elements for different menus in my site using CakePHP to create the links, eg:

```
echo $this->Html->link(
    'Home',
    array(
        'controller'=>'users',
        'action'=>'home'
    )
);
```

My links all break when using the full_calender plugin 2.0 branch from Github when I click the link to the full calender page located at
http://localhost/mysite/full_calendar

All the links in my element are broken and become:

> http://localhost/mysite/full_calendar/home/

instead of

> http://localhost/mysite/home

I've installed the plugin in app/plugin.

I'm using the controller name and view in my links in the element so whats going wrong?

Comment: Which is it, CakePHP 1.3 or 2.0?

Comment: its cakephp 2.0, the callendar works apart from this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by adding plugin link to the links not using the plugin;

```
echo $this->Html->link('home',array('plugin'=>'','controller'=>'users','action'=>'home'));
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using:

```
echo $this->Html->link('home',array('plugin'=>false,'controller'=>'users','action'=>'home'));
```

using

```
'plugin'=>false
```

works perfectly and it looks cleaner than 'plugin'=>''.